# Left space leftBarButtonItem for iPhone's

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus

In iPhone 6+ leftBarButtonItem has more left offset than other iPhone's (Other iPhone's have approximately the same left space). How can i get width of this space? Or maybe i can set width for this space for all iPhone's?

left - iphone5,
right - iphone6+

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help you to play around with offsets:

```
UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[leftButton sizeToFit];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onNavLeftLabelBarButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIView* leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 200, 44)];
//use the x and y to play around with the offset, changing it conditionally
//for Iphone 5 and 6+ for example
leftView.bounds = CGRectInset(leftView.frame, x2, y2); //play around with the insets
[leftView addSubview:self.leftButton];

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.leftView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
```

Comment: should i check for each iphone and set value?

Comment: @Nikita - Well, as you pointed out, the only difference you observe is between the Iphone 5/6 and the 6+. Hence, what you could do is simply check if (6+) {then x = ...) else {x = ...}